# Login verification from sqlite not working correctly

Tags: netbeans-8

Hi everyone I was told by a friend that if I struggle I should go on this website for some guidance. I am a casual after hours programmer and I just do it to enrich my mind. I have a problem at the moment where I want my program to have a login screen and use my sqlite database to verify the username, password and division (administrator, admin, user) before you get to log into the main menu of the program. Now I use Netbeans to do my java programming as it makes it way easier for me and so far it works for the first password and administrator "division" but as soon as I add someone as let say admin or a user nothing happens and I have tried everything I could read up on on the internet as I said I am home schooled when it comes to programming as it is just a hobby and a interest of mine, any advise or a pointer to a website where I can teach myself how to fix my problem will help me.Here is my current code I hope I am posting this correctly: 
`private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:

```
    String sql ="select Id,Username,Password,Division from Users where (username =? and password= ? and division=?)";

    try{
        int count = 0;
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setString(1, txt_username.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txt_password.getText());
        pst.setString(3, txt_combo.getSelectedItem().toString());

        rs = pst.executeQuery();
       while (rs.next()){
           int Username =rs.getInt(1);
           Emp.empnum = Username;
           String username = rs.getString("username");
           Emp.empname = username;
           count = count+1;
       }

        String access = (txt_combo.getSelectedItem().toString());

        if(access =="Administrator,Admin,User"){
            if(count == 1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success");
                MainMenu j = new MainMenu();
                j.setVisible(true);
                this.dispose();
            }else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Username or Password you entered was incorrect!");
            }
        }

    }catch (Exception e){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }
    finally {

        try{
            rs.close();
            pst.close();

        }catch (Exception e){
    }
    }
}`
```

Comment: Thanks I have figured this out I got it working right by just using a Boolean with a founduser true and false.

Answer (score 0):

IU found the function Boolean here is how my code worked perfectly after using it if anyone can see anyway I can better it any advise will do but it works 100%. 'String sql ="select Id,Username,Password,Division from Users where (username =? and password= ? and division=?)";

```
    try{

        int count = 0;
        boolean foundUser = false;
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);



        pst.setString(1, txt_username.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txt_password.getText());
        pst.setString(3, txt_combo.getSelectedItem().toString());


        rs = pst.executeQuery();
       while (rs.next()){
           int Username =rs.getInt(1);
           Emp.empnum = Username;
           String username = rs.getString("username");
           Emp.empname = username;
           foundUser = true; 
           count = count+1;

         }

    String access = (txt_combo.getSelectedItem().toString());       
    if (foundUser) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success");
                MainMenu j = new MainMenu();
                j.setVisible(true);
                this.dispose();

            }else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Username or Password you entered was incorrect!");
            }


    }catch (Exception e){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }
    finally {

        try{
            rs.close();
            pst.close();

        }catch (Exception e){
    }
    }'
```